# Shopify app development -production build failing to serve assets folder in dist/client/assets

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

Trying to get my Shopify app to work on a server. When I run npm run serve nothing is failing, OAUTH is working, but the index.html is throwing an error saying it can't get the static files in the dist/client/assets folder. Here is my server code, here is my index.html file, and the error Im getting. [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbyuN.png)
[server code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sydcg.png)
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOWUs.png)